# How do I find adjoint operator in different bases?

Tags: adjoint-operators

I know the Gram matrix $G$ of euclidean space my operator is in and the matrix $A$ of it. How do I use them to calculate adjoined operator?
I know I can use $A^*=\overline{G^{-1}A^TG}$
So for example if

$G= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

and

$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0& 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

i get

$G^{-1}A^TG = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 \\\ -1 & -3 & -3 & -2 \\\ 0& 1 &1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

but how do I get $\overline{G^{-1}A^TG}$?

Comment: Do you mean $G=(\langle e_i,  e_j\rangle)_{i, j} $? Then I'm not sure it's $G^{-1}$ in the formula.

Comment: It is not clear what you search. If you want the Hermitian adjoint  od conjugate transpose, this is  simply the transpose for a matrix with real entries. If you want the adjugate matrix, than it is the  transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Comment: I want to find $A^*$ so that   $(Ax,y)=(x,A^*y)$

Comment: Haven’t you’ve answered your own question? “I know I can use ...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix ${G^{-1}A^TG}$ has **real entries**, its conjugate is the  same of the matrix:

$\overline{G^{-1}A^TG}={G^{-1}A^TG}$